# Is it a good practice to use one jwt-secret for 2 different services?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Suppose i have in my application 2 main services, both using the jwt functionallities for different purposes.
One is an **authentication** service while the other handles **sending emails** with jwt-signed-tokens.

Would it be ok and safe to use **one** secret-key for *both*? Or rather use different secrets for *every* different service.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have the same signing key for all tokens in your system.

If you with JWT secret mean the token signing key.